# is this the correct way to rewrite calculus limit?

Tags: calculus, limits

Can
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^3-7x}{x^3}$$
be rewritten as
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^3(1-7x^{-2})}{x^3}?$$

These two seem to give different answers. Please help me I'm really confused :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did is fine.  The next step is to cancel the $x^3$ terms to get

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^3 - 7x}{x^3} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^3 (1 - 7x^{-2})}{x^3} = \lim_{x \to 0} 1 - 7x^{-2}$$

Now, we have a polynomial over a polynomial and we get division by 0 but the numerator of the fraction is not 0.  If it were a left or right hand limit, this would tell us the answer is $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ and we would only need to figure out which one it is.  If it's a limit (not right or left hand), there is the possibility that the left and right hand limits differ (one is $+\infty$ and the other is $-\infty$) so the limit could not exist.  But, as $x \to 0$, the whole thing $1 - 7x^{-2}$ is going to be negative no matter if you approach from the left or right.  Therefore, the left and right hand limits are both $-\infty$, so that the limit itself is $-\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Your rewrite is correct. The limit of the expression, in either form, does not exist.  Alternately, if you allow $\infty$ or $-\infty$ as possible answers to a limit question, the limit is $-\infty$.

A direct way to calculate the limit is to note that if $x\ne 0$, then
$$\frac{x^3-7x}{x^3}=1-\frac{7}{x^2}.$$

Comment: Maybe it is worth to mention something related to "punctured neighborhood" in a more pedagogical manner, to explain why $$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{{{x^3} - 7x}}{{{x^3}}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \left( {1 - \frac{7}{{{x^2}}}} \right)?$$

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: Thanks for the suggestion, I added something along the lines you mentioned, but without using the phrase "punctured neighborhood."

Comment: Yes. Using the phrase "punctured neighborhood" wouldn't really help.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff thanks for the term "punctured neighborhood", it gave me something to look up and "try" to understand.

Answer (score 1):

They are indeed the same:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^3-7x}{x^3}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^3(1-7x^{-2})}{x^3}=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(1-\frac7{x^2}\right)\;,$$ which does not exist. However, it fails to exist in a relatively nice way: as $x\to 0$, the expression in parentheses gets increasingly negative without any bound, so we often write

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(1-\frac7{x^2}\right)=-\infty\;.$$

Comment: Could you drop by the chat?